# How to get specified index from Array

Tags: angular

**Hello !**

I need to get variable (specified index) from array.
First I store in variable like this:

```html
<input type="hidden" value="{{notification[7] }}"  id="receiver"  >
```

Know I have my variable stored ( I'm using loop to get the data from array)

Then I send it  in post requests like this:

```js
this.notification.receiverId =  $('#receiver').val().toString() ;
```

Problem: the only data I get is the first, in angular I had warning that I have the same id for many input( due to the `*ngFor`). Please what I need to do to resolve this problem.

Comment: So first off, what will you do to resolve the issue of the `id`? Can you use interpolation to create a unique id for each `ngFor` generated input?

Comment: u resolved my issue thnx a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML :**
to display array :

```
 <div *ngFor="let notification of notifications; let i= index">
```

Function in button(in HTML) :

```
(click)="onSubmit(i)"
```

**Ts file :**

the index in the parameter of the function :

```
onSubmit(ind)
```

Now I can get any index (I need index 7 in my case) of the array it doesn't matter how many array I have :

```
this.notification.receiverId = this.notifications[ind][7];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set dynamic id based on index in `*ngFor`:

```
<div  *ngFor="let notification of notifications; let i= index">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{notification}}"  id="receiver{{i}}"  >
</div>
```

Comment: please in the ts file how can I get this Id ?

Comment: this.notification.receiverId =  $('#receiver{{i}}').val().toString() ;
:: this one is wrong

Comment: Use loop and index to find correspond id `for (var i = 0; i < this.notifications.length; i++) {let id = "receiver" + i;}`

Comment: sorry but i didn't get it : this is my code to get it:   this.notification.receiverId =  $('#receiver').val().toString() ;
where i need to put your code

Comment: @lili In your html you have `*ngFor` and that means you have lots of input. Now which input do you want?

Comment: <input type="hidden" value="{{notification[7] }}"  id="receiver"  >
: this one is my target but i have many input like this meanse I have more than one array has notification[7] : I have function will work on all of then the same way: but it needs to get the value of the specified array once click not the first one like it's working now !

Comment: `<input type="hidden" value="{{notification[7] }}" id="receiver" >` this is in `*ngFor`?

Comment: yes exactly   I'm getting array data with ngFor

Comment: OK in your typescript you need to loop through your array to get your id. Show me code to better help

Comment: Done, please check if u can .

Comment: you don't have one `receiverId` you have lots of it. you need to determine which do you want. Show `*ngFor` in your html too

Comment: yes I have many, I edited the post, check  it please.

Comment: OK Which `receiver` do you want? the `receiver` corresponding in  notification[7]??

Comment: I will use all of them , each button need to have his own receiver

Comment: OK you need to call function in `ngFor` and send `i` as a parameter of the function

Comment: But there is simple way. there is no need hidden input and jquery. Use this one: `<div *ngFor="let notification of notifications; let i= index">
        <button (click)="myFunction(notification)"></button>
    </div>`

Comment: Absolutely but you can use other way I told you in previous comment

Comment: in the ts file i get the value of notification[7] with his index only !! if it works i will accept it for sure

Comment: yes, i will share the solution

Comment: check the solution if u need, thnx for your time !

Comment: u didn't tell me how to do it my ts file :(  they are  related